# generate and share a pdf from sqlite datatable of inventory count using skiasharp .net maui

Tags: c#, maui, skiasharp

I want to design a professional looking pdf report of item count using skiaSharp but I have failed to get the proper code example of it.
I want to use an sqlite table, to generate the report grouped into item categories with category totals.

The code returns error on:

```
pdfDocument.ToArray())
```

> SKDocument doesn't contain a definition for 'ToArray'

Here is the code I tried tried.

```
        public async Task<SKDocument> GenerateInventoryItemCountPdfAsync(DateTime date, List<Item> items, string pdfLogoPath, string pdfTitle) 
         { 
             var stream = new MemoryStream(); 
             using var document = SKDocument.CreatePdf(stream); 
  
             var pageSize = new SKSize(595, 842); 
             using var canvas = document.BeginPage((int)pageSize.Width, (int)pageSize.Height); 
  
             using (var logoBitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(pdfLogoPath)) 
             { 
  
                 //var logoRect = SKRect.Create(pageSize.Width / 2 - logoBitmap.Width / 2, 50, logoBitmap.Width, logoBitmap.Height); 
                 //canvas.DrawBitmap(logoBitmap, logoRect); 
  
                 var titlePaint = new SKPaint 
                 { 
                     Typeface = SKTypeface.FromFamilyName("Arial", SKFontStyleWeight.Bold, SKFontStyleWidth.Normal, SKFontStyleSlant.Upright), 
                     TextSize = 24, 
                     IsAntialias = true, 
                     Color = SKColors.Black 
                 }; 
                 var titleBounds = new SKRect(); 
                 titlePaint.MeasureText(pdfTitle, ref titleBounds); 
                 canvas.DrawText(pdfTitle, pageSize.Width / 2 - titleBounds.Width / 2, 150, titlePaint); 
                 var countPaint = new SKPaint 
                 { 
                     Typeface = SKTypeface.FromFamilyName("Arial", SKFontStyleWeight.Bold, SKFontStyleWidth.Normal, SKFontStyleSlant.Upright), 
                     TextSize = 18, 
                     IsAntialias = true, 
                     Color = SKColors.Black 
                 }; 
                 var y = 200; 
                 foreach (var item in items) 
                 { 
                     var itemCount = await GetInventoryItemCountForDateAsync(date, item.Id);//.ConfigureAwait(false); 
                     string condition; 
                     if (itemCount != null) 
                     { 
                         condition = itemCount.InventoryItemUnitQty.ToString(); 
                     } 
                     else 
                     { 
                         condition = "N/A"; 
                     } 
  
                     var countText = $"{item.ItemFullName}:{condition}"; 
                     var countBounds = new SKRect(); 
                     countPaint.MeasureText(countText, ref countBounds); 
                     canvas.DrawText(countText, pageSize.Width / 2 - countBounds.Width / 2, y, countPaint); 
                     y += 30; 
  
                 } 
                 document.EndPage(); 
                 document.Close(); 
                 return document; 
             } 
         } 
         public List<InventoryActivityReport> GetAllInventoryActivityReports() 
         { 
             InitAsync(); 
             return conn.Table<InventoryActivityReport>().ToList(); 
         } 
         public List<InventoryCount> GetAllInventoryCounts() 
         { 
             InitAsync(); 
             return conn.Table<InventoryCount>().ToList(); 
         } 
         public InventoryActivityReport GetInventoryActivityReport(int id) 
         { 
             InitAsync(); 
             return conn.Table<InventoryActivityReport>().Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault(); 
         } 
         public InventoryCount GetInventoryCount(int id) 
         { 
             InitAsync(); 
             return conn.Table<InventoryCount>().Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault(); 
         } 
         public List<InventoryCount> GetInventoryCountsByInventoryActivityReportId(int id) 
         { 
             InitAsync(); 
             return conn.Table<InventoryCount>().Where(i => i.InventoryActivityReportID == id).ToList(); 
         } 
         public List<InventoryCount> GetInventoryCountsByInventoryReport(InventoryActivityReport inventoryActivityReport) 
         { 
             InitAsync(); 
             return conn.Table<InventoryCount>().Where(i => i.InventoryActivityReportID == inventoryActivityReport.Id).ToList(); 
         } 
  
         public async Task<InventoryCount> GetInventoryItemCountForDateAsync(DateTime date, int id) 
         { 
             InitAsync(); 
             return  conn.Table<InventoryCount>() 
                   .Where(ic => ic.CountedDate == date.Date && ic.ItemId == id) 
                   .FirstOrDefault(); 
                    
  
             //if (count != null) 
             //{ 
             //    return count; 
             //} 
             //else 
             //{ 
             //    return new InventoryCount(); 
             //} 
  
         } 
         public  InventoryCount GetInventoryItemCountForDate(DateTime date, int id) 
         { 
             InitAsync(); 
             //InventoryCount count = conn.Table<InventoryCount>().Where(ic => ic.CountedDate.Date == date.Date && ic.ItemId == id).FirstOrDefault(); 
             InventoryCount count = conn.Table<InventoryCount>() 
                 .Where(ic => ic.CountedDate == date.Date && ic.ItemId == id) 
                 .FirstOrDefault(); 
             if (count != null) 
             { 
                 return count; 
             } 
             else 
             { 
                 return new InventoryCount(); 
             } 
  
         } 
         
  
         public async Task ShareInventoryItemCountPdfAsync(DateTime date, List<Item> items, string pdfLogoPath, string pdfTitle) 
         { 
             var pdfDocument = await GenerateInventoryItemCountPdfAsync(date, items, pdfLogoPath, pdfTitle).ConfigureAwait(false); 
              
            //  var pdfStream = new MemoryStream(pdfDocument.ToArray()); 
             var pdfFile = new ShareFile("InventoryItemCount.pdf", "application/pdf"); 
             await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest { Title = "Share Inventory Item Count PDF", File = pdfFile }).ConfigureAwait(false); 
         } 
         public void UpdateInventoryCount(InventoryCount inventoryCount) 
         { 
             int result = 0; 
             try 
             { 
                 InitAsync(); 
                 if (inventoryCount != null) 
                 { 
                     result = conn.Update(inventoryCount); 
                 } 
             } 
             catch (Exception ex) 
             { 
             } 
         }
```

Comment: "the code returns error" - how are we supposed to know what the error is if you don't tell us?

Comment: It returns the error: SKDocument doesn't contain a definition for 'ToArray'

Comment: Are you trying to convert SKDocument to a byte[]?

Comment: Yes. In a memory stream.

Comment: There are multiple CreatePdf methods that will write to a stream

Comment: I am new to that, what do you recommend?

Comment: I don't know, read the docs and pick the one that makes the most sense for your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already putting the pdfdocument into a stream:
`var stream = new MemoryStream();`.

Return `stream` instead of returning pdfDocument:

```cs
public async Task<MemoryStream>` ...
  var stream = new MemoryStream();
  using var document = SKDocument.CreatePdf(stream);
  ...
  return stream;

// usage
var pdfStream = await GenerateInventoryItemCountPdfAsync(...
```